# I have a loadFile error. Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I was trying to implement a highscore system into my game but when i try to declare my highscore loadFile I get this error.

```
Attempt to call global 'loadFile' (a nil value)
```

Here is my code.

```
highscore = loadFile ("highscore.txt")

local function checkForFile ()
    if highscore == "empty" then
        highscore = 0
        saveFile("highscore.txt", highscore)
    end
end
checkForFile()

print ("Highscore is", highscore)

local function onSystemEvent ()
    if playerScore > tonumber(highscore) then
        --We use tonumber as highscore is a string when loaded
        saveFile("highscore.txt", score)
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "system", onSystemEvent )
```

I am using Corona SDK.

Comment: It means that the function `loadFile` doesn't exist. Also please indent your code.

Comment: The function "loadFile" does not exist. Would you mind giving us some information on which engine you are using?

Comment: I am using corona SDK. Also very sorry for the non indentions I am new to the forums posting! How would I go about creating loadFile?

Answer (score 3):

The developers of the corona ask published a nice [guide](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/data/readWriteFiles/index.html) about saving and writing to files, which should fulfill your needs.

Basically you get the path via *system.pathForFile* and then open it using *io.open*.

You would do it like this:

```
local path = system.pathForFile( "highscore.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )
local file = io.open(path, 'w+')
```

And then, to get the content of the file:

```
local content = file:read('*a')
local highscore

if (content ~= null)
    highscore = tonumber(content)
    // do stuff with the loaded highscore
end
```

And to write to the file:

```
file:write(highscore)
```

Answer (score 1):

The file you are loading is not a Lua file but a text file. So there is no point in using `loadfile` even if it existed. Use instead `io.read` with `file:read` or `file:lines` (where `file` is the object returned by `io.open()`).